MultiGlyph for same unicode sequences and Creating Variation in a single glyph in Fontforge
I am fairly new in designing a font (even in Fontforge). What I am trying to achieve is to digitise one font (Bengali). Because Bengali language has compound characters in it, I preferred downloading existing (Noto) Bengali Font and replace each glyph there. Now I am facing the following problems:

MultiGlyph for same Unicode Sequences: In Bengali, some compound characters may have more than one appearance. E.g. (ক + ত = ক্ত / ক্ত). This kind of variations have been achieved in LaTeX for example while writing calligraphic letters there are two fontfaces for D (one using mathcal, another using pazocal). How to define that in FontForge?

Variation in a Single Unicode: Consider how press works in ancient days -- they used to press some dye moulds on a paper and prints things. Now depending upon the impact of the press, the impression on the paper differs from one another. So can we design glyphs in such a way the curvatures change by a value say ε at random?


I would like to have some pointers to solve it of course using FontForge or by running some script within it. One thing to add, I would like to develop the font for LaTeX.
